# The maximum volume of water.

Tags: geometry

We are a group of math enthusiasts and we design and present our mathematical problems to societies. This week I designed this problem and I thought it might be interesting to share it with you here. If you think sharing such problems are not appropriate for this site, then I can remove it.
Here is the problem:- A spherical glass is resting on its side on a table. What is the maximum volume of water it can hold in that position?
We ignore the thickness of the glass edges.
The picture is designed and rendered in $PovRay$.
[image]

Comment: Sharing this type of problems is ok for this site. Do you have any ideas to solve it?

Comment: @Crostul, Yes I have the solution, because in our group every member should provide the solution of his designed  problem.

Comment: @RobertZ, It involves small angles and therefore we need to use trigonometry.

Comment: @Seyed After some unpleasant calculation I found that the maximum volume is  around $7.83415\pi$ (not a rational multiple of $\pi$.).

Comment: @RobertZ, Excellent work, well done. Your answer is correct but I don't think the calculation is unpleasant. It is all depends on how you approach the problem.

Comment: @Seyed Is the answer supposed to be an approximation or the exact value?

Comment: @RobertZ, It is not exact and your answer is correct.

Comment: @Seyed OK. Thanks for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we need the the volume of a [spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap):
$$V=\frac{\pi h}{6}(3a^2+h^2)$$
where $a$ is the radius of the base of the cap and $h$ is the height of the cap. In order to find $h$ and $a$ we consider Cartesian coordinate system with the $x$-axis along the glass axis and with the origin at the center of the base of the glass. Take the circle of center $(5+4,0)$ and of radius $4$ and the tangent line through $(0,5/2)$. The water level is a line parallel to this tangent which passes through the point $(5+4+\sqrt{4^2-(6/2)^2},6/2)$.

After some unpleasant calculation I found that the maximum volume is around $7.83415\pi$ (not a rational multiple of $\pi$).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to the maximum volume of water in a glass. The important step in this solution is to find the angle of rotation of the glass when it is resting on the table. 
[image]